# How do I replace missing values from a json file to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json-file which I loaded in the variable "tags". It contains of IDs and corresponding values. For each ID I want to add the values into columns of a dataframe. That works fine for the values 'X', 'Y', 'Z' as you see in the code below.

The format of my json file looks like:
{"1": ["X"], "2": ["Z"], "3": ["Y"], "4": ["X"]}

```
tags = json.load(f)
tags.items()
for key, value in tags.items():
    try:
        if 'X' in value:
            df.at[key, 'X'] = True
        if 'Y' in value:
            df.at[key, 'Y'] = True
        if 'Z' in value:
            df.at[key, 'Z'] = True
        else
            df.at[key, 'Q'] = True            

    except KeyError:
        pass
```

My problem is that I have some values in the json-file missing, and I want to replace them with "True" in a column Q of the dataframe. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give an example of what your dataframe/json looks like?

Comment: {"1": ["X"], "2": ["Z"], "3": ["Y"], "4": ["X"]}

Comment: What would a missing value look like in this case? Would it be of the form "5": []?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the missing data is like "5":[""]

```
from io import StringIO
import json
import pandas as pd

# Assume the missing value format
text = """
 {"1": ["X"], "2": ["Z"], "3": ["Y"], "4": ["X"], "5":[""]}
"""
# The index option makes the dataframe row-oriented with index values
df = pd.read_json(StringIO(text), orient="index")  

# Provide a maningful column name 
df.columns = ["variable"]

# Assign the Q value to missing 
df['variable'][df['variable'] == ""] = "Q"

# Pandas get_dummies does the transformation - (need pandas 0.24 for the dtype)
pd.get_dummies(df, prefix="", prefix_sep="", dtype=bool)
```

Results

```
       Q      X      Y      Z
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False   True
3  False  False   True  False
4  False   True  False  False
5   True  False  False  False
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your reply! I realized that the problem wasn't missing values in the json-file but rather that some of the IDs that exist in the dataframe don't exist in the json-file. I want to find these and add True for a column 'W' in the dataframe for those IDs missing in the json. I've tried things like: 

testid = df['ID'].to_string()        

for key, value in tags.items():
     if testid not in key:
            df.at[key, 'W'] = True

But don't get it to work. Do you have any ideas?